# Unable to use Microsoft Japanese IME in Emacs under Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, input-method, utf-8, inputs

For some reason I can't seem to use the Microsoft Japanese IME in Emacs, even though I can apparently use the Microsoft Chinese IME to input Chinese without problems. Even if I've switched to the Japanese IME, only English is entered, and I cannot change the input mode to Hiragana or Katakana. The only way to input Japanese seems to be to use the built-in Japanese input method in Emacs, which is much more inconvenient. Is there anybody who successfully managed to use external Japanese input methods in Windows Emacs?

I know that under Linux you must set `LC_CTYPE` to a CJK language in order to input such languages in Emacs. But since I can input Chinese just fine here, I don't think that's the problem.

The Emacs version I'm using comes from https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain? Is this question in any way irrelevant on this SE? Downvoting without leaving any comment surely is very helpful from you to me and to this community.

Comment: I must have attracted some real hater here as somebody downvoted two of my questions in succession without leaving any comments. Just wow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that if I go into Emacs with the Japanese IME already activated, the problem is fixed. I can use the shortcut for switching Kana/Romaji input as well, even though the IME icon in the status bar doesn't work.